# Allow a textarea resize to shrink (not just grow) element from its original/default size

Tags: javascript, resize, textarea, css

I am trying to create a `textarea` element that has a programmatically-defined original/default size, but which the user can resize within defined limits that allow it to both grow and shrink.

I have tried setting the `resize`, `min-width`, `max-width`, and `width` properties of the text-area, but, thus far, this only allows the user to *grow* the `textarea` element, not *shrink* it. The browser will allow the user to size and resize the element within the bounds of `width` and `max-width`, not between the bounds of `min-width` and `max-width`, as intended.

Is there a simple way of specifying a *default* size that will not also be treated as a *minimum* size?

---

Here is the code I am working with:

```
function textAreaWithDefault(size) {
    var ta = document.createElement("textArea");

    ta.style.resize = "both";
    ta.style.minWidth = "100px";
    ta.style.width = size + "px";    // default size
    ta.style.maxWidth = "500px";

    document.body.appendChild(ta);
}
```

A pure css and/or javascript solution is preferred, but it only has to work on web-kit.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into fittext or similar scripts:
http://fittextjs.com/

This does exactly what you are describing.

Comment: How is that so? He wants to shrink the textarea container, not the font size.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set min-width equal to max-width and width to 0

Comment: That just prevents the textarea element from shrinking **or** growing. I want it to shrink **and** grow.